# How to animate Activities of ActivityGroup

Tags: android, animation, transition, activitygroup

I am using an ActivityGroup and want a slide_in_up transition while new activity is started.
I am currently using `overridePendingTransition(...)` method but it has no effect on animation.

Here is the snippet which I am using to launch the new Activity.

```
View view = MainGroup.group.getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(NewsFeedScreen.TAG, intent  
    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))
    .getDecorView();  

    MainGroup.group.replaceView(view, NewsFeedScreen.TAG);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_up, 0);
```

here MainGroup is the ActivityGroup and NewsFeedScreen is the Activity I want to start with slide_in_up transition.

I have searched a lot but didn't find any solution. If anyone has a solution of similar sort of problem guys please help.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a ViewAnimator for this. Here is a part of my solution:

```
final Window window = mLocalActivityManager.startActivity(pId, pIntent);
final View view = window != null ? window.getDecorView() : null;
if (view != null) {
    mViewAnimator.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.pull_right_in));
    mViewAnimator.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.push_left_out));
    mViewAnimator.addView(view);
    mViewAnimator.showNext();    
}
```

When I go back to a previous activity I use showPrevious() and afterwards remove the view.

Comment: By using ViewAnimator, your solution looks better than others (such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532678/slide-transition-animation-in-a-activitygroup-on-android . But, could you please elaborate on your code and explain what ViewAnimator is doing and it's life cycle and role with the ActivityGroup?

Comment: Thanks Mokus, not using your answer directly, but it gives new thinking to solve my problem :-)

Comment: Today I don't use ActivityGroup and ViewAnimator anymore, I use Fragments instead, as they are easier to handle.