# Slide transition animation in a ActivityGroup on Android

Tags: android, animation, activitygroup

I want to add slide transition animation while changing activities within a ActivityGroup. I have used following function to change activities using intent:

```
public void replaceContentView(String id, Intent newIntent) {
    View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(id,
            newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))
            .getDecorView();
    history.add(view);
    this.setContentView(view);
}
```

Any suggestion how can I do that?

Comment: Stop editing the title with "solved". Just mark the correct answer with the big checkmark.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add animation to the view

### Example

```
public void replaceContentView(String id, Intent newIntent) {
    View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(id,
            newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))
            .getDecorView();

Animation hyperspaceJump = 
     AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.myanimation);
    view.startAnimation(hyperspaceJump);
 history.add(view);
    this.setContentView(view);
}
```

Comment: Hi Junaid how can you add solved tag to your question in stackoverflow?

Comment: Its not a tag ... , I just edited the Title from ' How To Use Slide Transition Animation In a ActivityGroup ' to ' How To Use Slide Transition Animation In a ActivityGroup [ Solved ] ' ......

Comment: This is just what I was looking for! So glad I came across this!